# The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context. Updated EDMX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using DB First with EF.. my database already exists so I have followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940014/asp-net-identity-with-ef-database-first-mvc5).. specifically stink's answer.

I have scripted the tables into my already existing database.

So now in my `web.config` I have this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-test-20170522025552.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-test-20170522025552;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
  <add name="FakeExistingDBConnectionString" connectionString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;user id=fake_user;password=fakeUser12;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
```

So the initial connection string `DefaultConnection` that came with the creation of this app is now commented out.

And in my IdenityModel.cs I have this now:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("FakeExistingDBConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

When I try and register a user.. I get this:

> The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Just to be clear.. my existing database does contain the `aspnetroles`, `aspnetuserclaims`, `aspnetuserlogins`, `aspnetuserroles`, `aspnetusers` tables.

How do I fix this?

**UPDATE**

Entire Connection String:

```
<add name="DatabaseNameEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.EntityDataModelName.csdl|res://*/Models.EntityDataModelName.ssdl|res://*/Models.EntityDataModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;user id=fake_user;password=fakePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**UPDATE 2**

Added this connection string to web.config:

```
<add name="NameConnString" connectionString="data source=serverName;initial catalog=databaseName;user id=fake_user;password=fakePassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then in my IdentityModel..

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("NameConnString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}
```

Comment: Make sure you update your EDMX by right clicking it. Otherwise, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25866700/change-asp-net-identity-to-use-existing-database).

Comment: @SteveGreene I've updated my EDMX from the database and it is still giving the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assumed this is your EF EDMX connection string:

```
<add name="FakeExistingDBConnectionString" connectionString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;user id=fake_user;password=fakeUser12;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

The connection string above most likely triggering the problem, since generated connection string uses `EntityClient` instead of `SqlClient` provider which required by EF to communicate with data source. Note that you need to include standard [SQL Server connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) targeting the DB where ASP .NET Identity tables created.

Hence, correct setup for your DB connection string should be like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="FakeExistingDBConnectionString" connectionString="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;user id=fake_user;password=fakeUser12;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Another connection string for EDMX:

```
<connectionStrings>       
    <add name="FakeExistingDBConnectionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelName.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelName.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelName.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;user id=fake_user;password=fakeUser12;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Additionally, the connection string referenced in `ApplicationDbContext` should refer to `SqlClient` provider connection string:

```
public ApplicationDbContext()
    : base("FakeExistingDBConnectionString", throwIfV1Schema: false)
{
}
```

Then, update the EDMX and ensure you can manage users (create, login, update, password reset etc.)

Similar issue:

[ASP.NET/Identity Error: The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22592770/asp-net-identity-error-the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model)

[The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context, DB First with custom user store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028014/the-entity-type-applicationuser-is-not-part-of-the-model-for-the-current-context)

Comment: So I just needed to add an extra connection string that doesn't have EF? See my update

Comment: Very well explained. Thank you @Tetsuya Yamamoto